# WordPress post count : X out of Y?

Tags: php, wordpress, count

I'm working on a theme with CPT.
In single-cpt.php, I want to show the post number out of the total posts.

I managed to show the total ok posts using :

```
   <?php $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'cpt_type',
    'post_status' => 'published',
    'numberposts' => -1
);
echo $num = count( get_posts( $args ) ); ?>
```

and it returns the total of posts for that CPT type. So, on each single cpt, I got the total number.

What I would like, is to have "post number" / "total posts". Example : 7/21, and when I go o the following post : 8/21 and so on...

So, how could I get each single post to have a "number"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paste this in functions.php:

```
function get_total_number_of_posts( $post ) {
    $posts = get_posts( array(
        'post_type'      => $post->post_type,
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    ) );

    return count( $posts );
}

function get_current_post_index( $post ) {
    $posts = get_posts( array(
        'post_type'      => $post->post_type,
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    ) );

    $index = 0;

    foreach ( $posts as $p ) {
        $index++;

        if ( $p->ID === $post->ID ) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return $index;
}
```

and then in your single.php file:

```
global $post;

$total_posts  = get_total_number_of_posts( $post );
$current_post = get_current_post_index( $post );

echo "You are viewing {$current_post} out of {$total_posts}";
```

Comment: THANKS!!!! It worked with a little tweak : I changed : 
'post_type'      => $post->post_type,
for
'post_type'      => 'my_post_type',